# Sass check if element contains another one

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to make buttons with icons. For the icons I want to use the `<i>` tag. For example, if I want a button with a star icon at the beginning I want to write something in sort of:

```
<a class="button" href="#"><i class="star"></i><span>Button</span></a>
```

The problem is that my by button could be without an icon. Is there any way in Sass to check this? If no, what is the best way to do it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to give a different style to the link, maybe you could avoid to use extra markup for styling purpose (it's a bad practice) and assign the class (e.g. `star`) to the link

```
<a class="button star" href="#"><span>Button</span></a>
```

and put the icon as content of a pseudoelement, e.g.

```
.button.star:before {
    content: url(...) // or some iconic font (e.g. fontello)
}
```

doing so you can have a different style for button with and without icon.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of Fabrizio is the best option but if you really want to go with the extra markup route, you could use a span instead of an  and nest the label span inside it :

```
<a class="button" href="#"><span class="star"><span>Button</span></span></a>
```

And adapt the CSS

```
.button .star {
    // Icon styles
}

.button span span {
    // Styles for the link when an icon is present
}
```